# Quotes for statistical game

Tags: probability-distributions

I have a simple scenario that displays quotes on a page. These quotes are numbers which players can choose, if certain events happen the player wins these quotes.

Now the quotes for this scenario are based on soccer players and specifically the scoring of them.

There are 22 players per match and I have statistics for each of them.

How would I go for thinking of a quote for each player based on the individual data.

I thought of something simple like this. Let $m$ be the number of matches the player played and $g$ the number of goals he scored (if 0 then 1):
$$ q = \frac{m}{g}$$

Problem with this is that the further you go into the season the higher the quotes will be, I need something that is more stable throughout the whole season.

Also because I use data from 2 seasons the variation between the number of matches per player is too big.

What kind of formula should I be looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compute $s_k = g_k/m_k$ for every player $k$. Then the quote of the player $n$ could be
$$
 q_n = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^N s_k}{s_n}
$$
where $N$ is the number of players.

Comment: It could work yes, only I have to see what to do with players that won't be playing. I calculate the statistics 10 mins before the game starts, then at the startmark the lineup is retrieved and players that are not lined up will be removed, thus making `N` a different number. Maybe I can always use a fixed number of 22 players.